# Create temporary table in hive

Tags: hive, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temporary table in hive to reduce the number of stages as some cte's are called multiple times. The code I am trying to use is of the form:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_schema.table_2 as 
select id,
    start_date
from my_schema.table_1
```

However, I get the error: "mismatched input 'temporary'"

I have the up to date version (23.0.0), The documentation seems to suggest this is the correct way for creating a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

What is your hive version ?
If version is 0.14.0 or higher, your `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`  will work. It seems the info you gave isn't a hive version. Latest Apache hive version is 3.1.3.

Now, if your hive is of lower version, i think you can `create external table` on top of S3 or something which will reduce your HDFS cost significantly.

Comment: Apopogies, I am giving the wrong number. That is the version of DBeaver, which is what I am using to access the hive database. It seems there is a custom installation, which might be the reason for the command not working.